# Taxact workflow with respect to choosing filing status?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Is anyone using Taxact software for filing tax 2012? I tried to use it, there is a thing.
If I want to file tax using Married Filing Separately as the filing status, do I have to buy two software copies? Money is not the issue. The question is below.

Now the workflow I encountered is when I finish my information, the system reminded me to input my credit information and submit my E-Filing. I dared not to do it because I don't know what is the next step. Is the next step to input my spouse's information or I need to buy a new software. I don't know whether Married Filing Separately is better than joint filing. If it is one software can process two pieces, then before the submitting I can view the total refund. Then I can make the final decision whether joint or separate filing.

You know once I submit my Married Filing Separately, it might be hard to go back.

Comment: Can't help you out with regard to TaxAct, but ost tax preparation software programs allow for _creating_ multiple tax returns. You can stop work on one return, save the document, and open another tax return at any time. Most also allow for electronic filing of multiple tax returns, though extra filing fees might be charged for the electronic filing of more than one return. You can, of course, print out the return(s) and file paper copies. Also, except in unusual and special circumstances, Married Filing Jointly results in payment of less total tax than Married Filing Separately.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be contacting TaxAct directly for their information.

If you do enter your spouses information and choose to purchase their deluxe product, I would think you might end up paying for the second efile.

I have used their deluxe version for many years now, but choose it mostly because of the free state efiling and not for the ability to determine whether or not to file separately.  In my case, it makes sense to file jointly and not file separately.

The deluxe version allows you to portion out your deductions and see which method of filing gives you the lowest total tax bill.

Here's the link directly to TaxAct's support:
https://www.taxact.com/tsupport/support_request.asp